# how to implement ARVR controller in unity & vuforia

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, augmented-reality, vuforia

hello i've been strugling figuring out this thing. i'm trying to make ar controller for my vr cardboard game, so the idea is using AR and VR simultaniously. you will completely in vr game but your phone camera wil be turned on and set to AR mode. while you're in vr mode and your AR camera will detect your marker and repositioned it based on your view and the distance between camera and object. that marker will appear in your vr game and you'll make it as a controller. then maybe you want to make that marker appear as a gun, a sword, a shield or whatever it is that can be work with this concept

or maybe you just can watch it to get the idea if my explanation is not clear enough https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_v_a23u6n0

so i'm trying to implement it with vuforia as it's augmented reality API and of course Unity. now i'm on the stage where i already now how to use AR & VR simultaniously and how to transtition between AR to VR or otherwise. i'm still strugling on how to re-potitioning my marker to correct position in my VR world.

i already tried asking this in vuforia forum but there's still no answer until now. if you guys can help me with this it would be a big help !!

thx before

Comment: youtube is good start: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vuforia+unity. The marker shown in the video above (Realiteer Controller) isn't available as Unitypackage but it should be possible to achieve the same with vuforia and regular markers

Comment: I already tried searching on YouTube since i started making this arvr controller (It's been more than 3 month) with various keyword combination, And not just YouTube i also try searching on Google, unity forum, vuforia forum, And other websites And until now, no luck

I assume there's no detailed, step by step documentation about this arvr controller available on the internet now, And if there's documentation exist, It would be super hard to find. And that's what's bring me here, for the first time asking in this forum

Comment: Hm. Wasn't meant to be offending. For me your question sounded like you would be in an early stagenl. Maybe you could go more into detail on what you have and what you used (your setup) so people could get a better idea how they could help you